# Magento 1.8 empty admin

Tags: admin, magento-1.8

I tried to upgrade Magento to 1.8. on my localhost version.
The front-end works well, but my admin is completely empty. No error messages, nothing.

I removed the sessions, the cache and commented out the cookieparams with no result.

Where do i have to look?

Thnx!

Comment: While upgrading, did you drop whole database?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check `magento_site/var/log/exception.log` and `magento_site/var/log/system.log` files.
2. If (1) didn't help, turn on error reporting in `php.ini`. Set `$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE']` variable so something not-empty (`true` is OK). Reload  page.

Comment: Thnx for the help. I think my installation was failed. An update with ssh is succeeded.